# System.IO.Directory.Getfiles Silverlight 4 is not working

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm using Silverlight 4 OOB & elevated trust.

I need to get all the filenames on specific directory & populate an object List(Of String)

The compiler throws an error "Method not found" on .Getfiles() method.

```
Dim files() As String = System.IO.Directory.Getfiles(Path) 'this line is failing..
```

Help!

Comment: Don´t know if you made a mistake in your question. But the method name ist GetFiles(string) not Getfiles(string). May be its also the solution for your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetFiles` is marked as "Security Critical" and therefore cannot be used from your code.

You will want to use the `EnumerateFiles` method instead.  `GetFiles` is sooo .NET 1.0, `EnumerateFiles` is much slicker, even in the full framework you'd want avoid this older Array returning API if you can.

Comment: Here's an alternative solution: Dim files = From i In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path)

Comment: @someonewhowillnotbemiss: That is not doing anything different from `Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path)`. This is sufficient to perform a `For Each` over.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot directly access the whole hard drive using Silverlight OOB.

Quoting from Silverlight site:

> When running in a trusted environment, you can access only files in
>   user folders, specifically the MyDocuments, MyMusic, MyPictures, and
>   MyVideos folders. Although this makes sense from a security point of
>   view, it’s limiting. You want to enable the user to drag their data
>   from any location. As it stands right now, if you try to drop a file
>   from a location other than stated above, Silverlight will throw a
>   security error.

Please refer to this link for details on how to work with the hard drive using Silverlight OOB:
http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/out-of-browser-applications/advanced-silverlight-out-of-browser-introduction#Exercise3

Comment: Hi, either way IO.Directory doesn't have GetFiles() method

Comment: @MichaelS: The error is thrown during compile time, not runtime, so the limitation of hard drive access doesn´t count here.

Comment: @Jehof, it's seems like this method is not available by design, hence not compiling. See the following link: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/223003/535951.aspx

Comment: Here's an alternative solution: Dim files = From i In Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path)

Comment: @MichaelS, Thanks for pointing it out, I usually save my file under a subfolder on a special folder like "My Documents" directory